# Range class to represent limited values, like HP, Stamina and so on

Tags: c#, unity3d, role-playing-game

I made a small script for Unity3D, meant to be use as GameComponent for GameObjects. It is supposed to represent values that have a max value, and an actual value. In games that would be the case, for instance, for the Health Points, the Stamina, Magic Points and so on. I would love to hear your feedback.

```
/////////////
//
// This is meant for things like Stamina, or HP. You have a max
// value, and an actual value.
//
// It inherits from MonoBehaviour because it is meant to be used
// as a Game Object Component
//
/////////////

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Range : MonoBehaviour {

    private int val, max;

    public Slider slider;

    // Is/Has/Can

    public bool IsDepleted() { return val == 0;    }
    public bool IsFull()     { return val == max; }

    public bool HasAtLeast(int _val) { return this.val >= _val; }

    // Actions

    public void Fill()    { val = max; }
    public void Deplete() { val = 0;   }

    public void Increase(int _val) { this.SetValue(this.val + _val); }
    public void Decrease(int _val) { this.SetValue(this.val - _val); }

    // Getters

    public int GetValue() { return this.val; }
    public int GetMax()   { return this.max; }

    // Setters

    public void SetValue(int amount) {
        if (amount > this.max) this.Fill();
        else if (amount < 0) this.Deplete();
        else this.val = amount;

        UpdateSlider();
    }

    public void SetMax(int amount) {
        this.max = amount;
        if (this.val > this.max) this.Fill();

        UpdateSlider();
    }

    private void UpdateSlider() {
        if (slider) {
            slider.maxValue = this.max;
            slider.value = val;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't judge your code idioms because I don't know unity3D, but I love to give feedback for sake of fun. If I was contributing to your code, I would add "public bool HasLessThan(int _val) {return this.val <= _val;}" at it/has/can section so you can trigger events when stamina has gone below certain threshold or something.

Comment: There is one thing I have to ask though; could slider.maxValue be set within a constructor? Again, I don't know C# or unit3d idioms so I have to ask. Setting it on every update seems redundant to me.

Comment: `HasLessThan`is actually just the opposite of `HasAtLeast`, no? Is it the same as negating that method. About the Constructor, i didn't add it, because the class was not meanth to be used directly, but for inheritance. But it is not a bad idea.

Comment: You are right, HasLessThan is supposed to be opposite of HasAtLeast and you should be able to just negate it. I accidentally introduced a bug with the equal sign in the HasAtLeast function... I guess my commit was... rejected.. (•_•) / ( •_•)>⌐■-■ / (⌐■_■)

Comment: Appreciated in any case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problematic**
Fill and Deplete are public, but don't call UpdateSlider, whereas Increment/Decrement do.

SetMax should reject values < 0 (0 could be allowed, for value forced to 0)

**Design Style**
There is a function in the Unity Mathf static class that does bounds checking Mathf.Clamp

C# has properties, while you can have the pair GetX/SetX they are preferred.

```
public int Value { 
    get { return val; } 
    set { val = Mathf.Clamp( value, 0, Max ); 
        UpdateSlider(); } }
public int Max { 
    get { return max; } 
    set { if ( value < 0 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("Max"); 
        max = value; } }
```

**Consider**
Increment and Decrement could be replaced by overriding + and -, as += and -= will use such overloads.

Comment: Those suggestions are wonderful! Could you give me an example of how would overloading the `+`operator look like? I have been trying for a while and I am a little confused about the syntax

Comment: Also please keep in mind that I would like `Range` to be inheritable, so the child classes should also be able to use the operator overload.

Comment: Overloading operators is basically incompatible with inheritance. Why do you want to inherit Range?

Comment: Well, I wanted HP`and `Stamina` to work like Range, but with their own particularities. Do you think I will have to implement it directly on each Child Class, even if they do the same?

Comment: I think you are using inheritance too much. I don't think HP needs to be a class

Comment: Well, my controller was getting super big, so I wanted to modularize my code as much as possible, and handle all the logic (like adding too much points, or removing more than was possible) in a separate file.